# Can I search something on specific filename in IntelliJ idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am a beginner of IntelliJ, but it's hard to find out how can I do it or not.

ex) I want to find keyword "apple"

and I have some files like

animal1.txt
animal2.txt
animal3.txt
fruits1.txt
fruits2.txt
fruits3.txt

I assumed "apple" is in fruits files then How can I search this?

Thank you!

I tried to Find on file in IntelliJ ver 2022.3.2 community and Mac.

Comment: if you use default key settings, press [cmd + shift + F]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html

Comment: Check the guide here if you want to search something in project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html
Check here if you want to search in a file directly: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html